# Rails 4 validation accepting empty value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Dog model which is related to the User model.

```
class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  validates :name, :presence => true

end
```

Creating a new dog:

```
  = form_for([@user, @user.dogs.build]) do |s|
    = render 'shared/dog_form', :s => s
```

For some reason the validation is not working.  It lets me create a new dog even when the :name value is ""

I used similar validation on the User model and it works fine.  Thoughts?

Comment: There's the `:allow_blank` option which should default to false, but maybe putting it in there explicitly would help? Try `validates :name, :presence => true, :allow_blank => false`.

Comment: Tried it.  Still lets me create new Dog with no name.

Comment: @user2573222 have check restarting your server ??

Comment: Do you have the project on Github or somewhere that we could try to play around with it? This is a strange bug.

Comment: Yeah, I have restarted the server.  The project is private, sorry.

Comment: Maybe it's related to the way my create method is constructed?                   `def create
    @user = current_user
    @dog = @user.dogs.create(dog_params)
    redirect_to user_path(current_user), :notice => "#{@dog.name} was added successfully."
  end`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `allow_blank: false`. Though `presence` should have worked. `Presence` uses the `blank?` method of object to check if the value is `nil` or blank. See if below code works.

```
class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  validates :name, presence: true, allow_blank: false

end
```

Comment: Nope, adding allow_blank: false didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use strict: true, this will raise error as you expecting.

```
class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates :name, presence: { strict: true }
end
```

Comment: Following the above suggestion I'm getting the following error: `ActiveModel::StrictValidationFailed in DogsController#create`